# Where did the term BBEG come from?

Tags: history-of-gaming, terminology

BBEG means "Big Bad Evil Guy" and refers to the villain of a campaign. My question is, where did it come from? How did it get made, and who popularized it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### Trollbill<sup>1</sup> first used the term

According [to the (archived, community-made) D&D Dictionary of Terminology](http://www.swgemu.com/archive/scrapbookv51/data/20070213163940/t-20521.html), it was coined during a discussion on a Wizard's message board back in 2001, by a poster called *trollbill* (who also wrote the post that kept the etymology on record in the link).

> Big Bad Evil Guy [BBEG] (term): An arch-villain, -nemesis, or -foil
>   used by the DM, often in a recurring role, as the climax to an
>   adventure, story arc or campaign.
>
> Etymology: D & D Message Boards, term first used in the thread 
>   [Honesty vs. Story](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20030220203503/http://boards.wizards.com/rpg-bin/ultimatebb.cgi?ubb=get_topic&f=136&t=000665&p=).

The beginning of that post (Honesty vs. Story) ...

> Okay, here's the scenario:
>   You have just spent the last 10 game
>   sessions building up Big Bad Evil Guy (BBEG) in a grand story arc that
>   has the PCs truly salivating for his blood. Finally, the PCs get to
>   confront him. You've built BBEG up, using some nasty power play
>   options, into a truly nasty opponent. The scene is set, the PCs have
>   waded through the minions and it is time now for the final climactic
>   battle with BBEG and his personal guard.

---

<sup>1</sup> Not sure who trollbill is, but that's the attribution and origin based on some research.

A related term, [Big Bad,](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BigBad) originated in the TV show *Buffy the Vampire Slayer* and [likely informed the inspiration for BBEG](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/129939/22566); its usage appears to be anchored in that show's particular style.

Answer (score 23):

As the aforementioned trollbill, I would just like to comment that when I had first used the term, it was just something that popped into my head, so at the time I assumed I had heard it before. Later, after seeing newb's to WotC's message boards constantly asking the meaning of common terms over and over again, I decided to create my Lexicon. BBEG was one of the common terms newbs would ask about so I added it to the Lexicon. When I did the research for the etymology of the term, I was actually surprised that the earliest reference I could find of the term was one of my own posts. Now, if anyone else can find an earlier reference, I'm fine with that, but I did try to be honest in my research. As far as the term being influenced by 'The Big Bad' from Buffy...yeah...probably.

Comment: Thanks for dropping by, Bill.  Sorry I didn't mention that earlier.